# How to keep site's structure in different screens?

Tags: html, css

When we create page , how to ensure that the page will look same on every screen ?
I am doing it for tablets.
I can set a class by 700px or 900px width , but what if a higher resolution tablet load the site?
There will be empty space in the left and right .
How to avoid that?

Comment: You can use responsive web Design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may use Responsive Web designing. Personally I am recommending **Twitter bootstrap**.

See the documentation [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) . Its very easy.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that bad to have some white space - it gives eyes some room to relax as well. You are never going to be able to fit all resolutions, so just make your design a little more flexible.